# How to configure whisper in VSCode for typescript types imports

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I would like to ask you about whisper in VS code for typescript.

I am importing interface `IQueryPreparePaymentsArgs` from some another file (see image). The whisper show me that its `IQueryPreparePaymentsArgs` is interface (it is good, thank you whisper), but is should allow me to see a content of this interface.

Is there any way (extension?) how to enable fully whisper like what is inside:

```
export interface IQueryPreparePaymentArgs {
  requestId: string;
}
```

Current state is not helpful for me.

Thank you in advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- You can navigate to the interface via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left click</kbd>
- Peek the interface via hover + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
  [image]
- Peek the definition via <kbd>right click</kbd> context menu
  [image]
- Peek the definition from Command Palette
  [image]